# How to skip a document based on condition in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let say I have a schema of blog post which contain many keys and one of them is author (ObjectId). Now I have an another collection of Block users which contains two keys: userid (ObjectId) and userWhoHasBeenBlocked (ObjectId).

Now in aggregation I want to skip those collection which has a author equals to the userWhoHasBeenBlocked. 
My Approch: First level I have a match query which chcecks the country from which the post has been made. Let say there is a key of a country.

After this I have a $lookup query for block user collection as

```
   { $match: { country: "usa" } },
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "ublocks",
                    let: { whoHasBeenBlocked: "$author", currentUser: userid },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match:
                            {
                                $expr:
                                {
                                    $and:
                                        [

                                            { $eq: ["$blockedUser", "$$whoHasBeenBlocked"] },

                                        ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    as: "isBlocked"
                },
            }
},
 { $match: { "$author": { $ne: "$isBlocked.userId" } } }
}
```

after this I have $projection block. this is not working. How to skip a document within aggregation. I also have pagination after this.

Comment: Could you post the sample collections and the desired output

Comment: I just want to skip the collection which matches the condition.

Comment: I read that. I just want to know the exact field names so   that it can be answered at once

Comment: I have solved that issue, I have made a condition on $projection that will return true/false to the projection field. After that I have made a $match to fetch only those collection which has key with true values. Thanks

Comment: Just put either an answer or delete the question.